# Expanding Prolog clauses without parameters

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I am writing a program that transforms other programs by expanding predicates. I usually do this using [`clause/2,`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=clause/2) but it doesn't always expand a predicate if it has no parameters:

```
:- set_prolog_flag('double_quotes','chars').
:- initialization(main).

main :- clause(thing,C),writeln(C).
% this prints "true" instead of "A = 1"

thing :- A = 1.
```

Is it possible to expand predicates that have no parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Some general remark: Note that this code is highly specific to SWI. In other systems which are ISO conforming you can only access definitions via `clause/2`, if that predicate happens to be `dynamic`.

For SWI, say `listing.` to see what is happening.

```
?- assert(( thing :- A = 1 )).
true.

?- listing(thing).
:- dynamic thing/0.

thing.

true.

?- assert(( thing :- p(A) = p(1) )).
true.

?- assert(( thing(X) :- Y = 2 )).
true.

?- listing(thing).
:- dynamic thing/0.

thing.
thing :-
    p(_)=p(1).

:- dynamic thing/1.

thing(_).

true.
```

It all looks like some tiny source level optimization.

Comment: `clause/2` sometimes expands clauses that have no parameters, but not always. If I change the definition to `thing :- A == 1`, then `clause(thing,A)` expands the body of the clause instead of unifying `A` with `true`. I'm still looking for an alternative to `clause/2` that works more consistently.

Comment: *expands clauses that have no parameters*, and also clauses that do have parameters. See `thing/1` above. Not sure what you want to do that interferes with this little transformation.